# vuejs and vuex || find data from v-for to get another data

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently doing my capstone project in our school. Currently I am using nuxt, vue, vuex, and vuetify for my csr and express for ssr.
In my code I want to fetch a data from v-for then pass to my component to query another data..

```
//my code in parent component
<template>
  <v-list-group v-else v-for='(items, index) in halfpayments' :key="index">
    <v-list-tile slot='activator'>
      <v-list-tile-title><span class="subheading">{{items.ordnameto}}</span></v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-list-tile>
    <halfpay text='black--text' :ids='items.id'/>
</v-list-group>
</template>
<script>
import halfpay from '@/components/custom/fullHalfpay'
export default {
 components: {
  halfpay
 }
}

//code in child component
<template>
 <v-flex>
 <v-list-tile v-for='(item) in data' :key="item.id">
  <v-list-tile-content>
   <v-list-tile-sub-title><span class="caption">Full payment date: </span><span :class="text">{{$dateFilter(item.paid_time)}}</span></v-list-tile-sub-title>
  </v-list-tile-content>
  </v-list-tile>
 </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
 export default{
  props: {
   ids: {
    type: String,
    required: true
   },
   text:{
    type: String,
    required: true
   }
  },
  computed: {
   data(){
    return this.$store.getters.halffullpay(this.ids)
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

the output of it, the v-for will render all the data of the child component. Is there a way to get the data in specific way. The only way is to merge the 2 separate data but it complicates the logic in the long run because the child node is a conditional render which it need to satisfy a condition to apply the child component.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) in your DOM. Your scripts will set `this.dataFromAPI` each time the API returns data, and your computed property (or multiple) will format that data as needed. Or the computed property of the child component is based off "input" props. (I couldn't quite tell from your code).

`.map()` it, `.reduce()` it, whatever you need.

You use the computed property name just like another data prop in your DOM, as if `this.computedData` was on your data().